# Provide a more unique name for the indicated resources in this project - Oracle ADF Mobile

Tags: android, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I am having issue deploying Oracle's Campus Mobile on Android Emulator. It is showing me error:

```
Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
Deployment cancelled.
----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
Rule=project-has-any-adf-model-techscope on MetaClass[ classLoader=oracle.ide.osgi.extension.internal.ClassLoaderProxy@550875, className=oracle.adfdt.model.deploy.rc.AdfmListenerImpl]
The commonly named resources listed below could cause reusability errors for your consumers.
Provide a more unique name for the indicated resources in this project, or start with a different project. You can also use the Validation panel in the profile to ignore the error, and create the jar.
DataBindings.cpx
DataControls.dcx
(oracle.adfdt.model.deploy.rc.AdfmDeployContext)
```

How to fix this **DataBindings.cpx** and **DataControls.dcx**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by changing the deployment profile. Previously, I was deploying it using **ADF Mobile for Android** but then I changed the deployment profile to **ADF Mobile Application Archive** and it deployed successfully on Android Emulator.

See the screen shot.

[image]